# C# check if object is out of bounds (GUI)

Tags: c#

I'm making a moving rectangle in C# WFA. It's moving without problems, but it can go away from my GUI so I need to check if my rectangle is out of bound. I've tried it, but it works only in left-up corner. Thanks for your help (my window is 400x400)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Object
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            enum Directions { Left, Right, Up, Down }
            Directions _direct;
            private int _x;
            private int _y;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _x = 50;
                _y = 50;
                _direct = Directions.Down;
            }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void form_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, _x, _y, 70, 70);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_direct == Directions.Left)
            {
                _x -= 10;
                checkPosition(_x, _y);
            }
            else if (_direct == Directions.Right)
            {
                _x += 10;
                checkPosition(_x, _y);
            }
            else if (_direct == Directions.Down)
            {
                _y += 10;
                checkPosition(_x, _y);
            }
            else if (_direct == Directions.Up)
            {
                _y -= 10;
                checkPosition(_x, _y);
            }

            Invalidate();
            checkPosition(_x, _y);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                _direct = Directions.Left;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                _direct = Directions.Right;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                _direct = Directions.Up;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                _direct = Directions.Down;
            }
        }

        private void checkPosition(int x, int y) {
            if (x < 0) {
                _x = 0;
            }
            else if (y < 0) {
                _y = 0;
            }
            else if ((x + 70) > 400) { _x = 330; }
            else if ((y+70)>400) {_y=330;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least remove all `else` in `checkPosition`, in this particual case it doesn't look like the cause but later on it could bite you.

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem is, but note that your code could potentially lead to sporadic jittery movement if the rectangle touches a border. Since the timer1_tick method probably runs on another thread than the UI thread, it is possible that the UI redraws the rectangle in the moment after incrementing/decrementing _x or _y but before the checkPosition method is called for boundary checking. A better approach is to only set _x and _y *after* boundary checks and do the additions/subtractions with temp variables (you could use System.Drawing.Point instead of two int variables, for example)

Comment: Interesting :-) Thanks ,I will try it :) Problem is that my rectangle goes out of my window resolution ,for example in left-up corner it stops and I see entire rectangle but in right-down corner it stops that I see only a half of my rectangle,a part of it goes out of my window :P

Comment: Hmm, your example code given does not reveal any suspicious. I would suggest you examine your real code closely and try to understand all what is going on. Perhaps your window is not being set to 400x400 but in reality smaller. Look also what your code is doing with the Graphics object in the PaintEventArgs. Perhaps it has a transformation or a scaling applied to it (see [Graphics documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) for all its properties/methods that can cause a potential coordinate transformation). (continued...)

Comment: There are a number of other reasons that might be responsible for what you see. But most importantly, use the debugger to check on the values of _x and _y as well as the properties of e.Graphics when the rectangle has travelled beyond your window boundaries...

Comment: Maybe question like this: I have a main window (300x300) and a square (50x50) but when I want to print it on [0,250] I can't see it,only upper part

Comment: See my two previous comments... You will need to examine your code and use the debugger to inspect the values of your variables and properties of objects involved in painting your rectangle (such as e.Graphics, for example). Wild guessing on my part will only help me wasting my time and you being entertained by my ramblings, but will likely not resolve the situation... ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how to inspect the values with the debugger :P

Comment: Well, i guess you have given yourself some homework :) Learn the basics of how to use the debugger. It is an essential tool, and writing code while being unable to debug it is a rather painful endeavor (as you experience right now). Google for something like "c# debugger tutorial". I don't have a particular recommendation for a tutorial, but i am optimistic that there will be something useful in the first handful of search results...

Answer (score 1):

Your rectangle is contained within client rectangle if the intersection between your rectangle and client rectangle is your rectangle. Use this check:

```
// rectangle is your rectangle
bool outOfBounds=!(Rectangle.Intersect(ClientRectangle, rectangle).Equals(rectangle))
```